# add space in html when using php echo

Tags: php

I am writing a html class attribute which need space to allow multiple values. However, among these values, there are variables and constants. Code shows below:

```
<article id="portfolio-item-1" data-loader="include/ajax/portfolio-ajax-image.php" class="value1 value2">
```

Here I want value1 in the class to be a variable like $itemTitle, but still to maintain the "value2" with a space between them.

I have tried many method like add &nbsp and using 
    **echo $itemName." "."value2";** 
but seems didn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Solved:

Solution1:

```
<article id="portfolio-item-1" data-loader="include/ajax/portfolio-ajax-image.php" class="<?php echo "$item->category_id"." "."value0"; ?>" >
```

Solution2:

```
<article id="portfolio-item-1" data-loader="include/ajax/portfolio-ajax-image.php" class="<?php echo "$item->category_id Value0"; ?>" >
```

Thanks!

Comment: class="<?php=$itemName?> value2" ?

Comment: @DimaK too simple, needs to be more complicated ;) ~ `class="<?= implode(' ', [$itemName, 'value2']) ?>"`. Also, does `<?php=` actually work? I thought it was only `<?php echo` or `<?=`

Comment: You can also use `&nbsp;` instead of " " to force a white space in html.

Comment: @skroczek not in a class attriubute

Comment: @Phil and its also mentioned in the OP. Shame on me...

Comment: Oh wait, this one's even betterer ~ `class="<?= implode(' ', array_map('htmlspecialchars', [$itemName, 'value2'])) ?>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "$itemName value2";
?>
```

If you use double quotes, you can drop the variable right in there, no concatenation needed!

```
<article id="portfolio-item-1" data-loader="include/ajax/portfolio-ajax-image.php" class="<?php echo "$itemName value2"; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error to have a space without a class on each side.

```
echo '<article... class="'.$itemName.' value2"...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id  = 'portfolio-item-1';
$url = 'include/ajax/portfolio-ajax-image.php';
echo '<article id="'.$id.'" data-loader="'.$url.'" class="'.$itemName.' value2">';
```

will work, for instance.